# Can't connect to local mysql server

Tags: mysql, sockets, connection, local

I get an error trying to connect to my mysql database, I'm quite a PHP/mysql amateur so I hope you guys can help me out since I'm stuck.

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: 
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'\
(2) in /public/sites/www.kernlab.nl/website/index.php on line 13

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be
established in /public/sites/www.kernlab.nl/website/index.php on line 13
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Below is how I try to connect to my database:

```
<?php
$db_host = "host";
$db_username = "user";
$db_password = "pass";
$db_database = "db";
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password) or die("Cannot connect");
  mysqli_select_db($link, $db_database) or die("Cannot select database");
?>
```

This how I try to echo the data:

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM ditdoenweblokken ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()) ;
while($rij = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
?>
<li><a style="height:150px;width:150px;" class="fancybox" href="#inline<?php echo($rij['id']);?>">
    <p style="font-weight:bold;"><?php echo($rij['titel']);?></p>
    <?php echo($rij['quote']);?></a>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
```

I get the feeling the problem is not in the script itself but somewhere in the mysql server? Hope you guys can help since I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem might be that you are connecting to the server using mysqli_connect but you are trying to run a query using mysql_query.

Try using mysqli to run the query.

Here is the manual for mysqli [MYSQLi Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

On a side note, this might help when thinking about how you get your data from your database and the security of it:

[Net Tuts - The Problem with PHP’s Prepared Statements](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/the-problem-with-phps-prepared-statements/)

You can either change the way you connect to you server, using mysql like so:
    mysql_connect(servername,username,password);

However this is not secure. Or you can change the way you are doing the query as stated before.

First you need to get the connection so lets say you store it in $mysqli Then we can run the query:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM ditdoenweblokken ORDER BY id DESC);
```

Now you can check to see if anything has been returned from the query.

Comment: No problem. Hope the extra info helped as well. Also the php manuals are a really good place to start when you have some sort of bug.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting to `mysqli_connect` and running queries in `mysql_query`, thats why its not establishing connection.

Assuming you are including the file as well in correct manner ;)

Comment: How do I fix this? I've been using this same code several times, how come it did work before?

Comment: im including the config part in the header which is included on every page

Comment: @BoudewijnSmit including file comment was just a safe side comment though ;)

Comment: editted the echo-ing part to mysqli, it's working fine now. Thanks :)

Comment: @BoudewijnSmit you can try by changing mysqli_connect to mysql _connect & mysqli_select_db to mysql_select_db....although u you need to use mysqli or PDO for safe side :)